# I don't want git clone to save the password in the git config file

Tags: git

When using clone using the following command style:

```
git clone "https://user:password@server.com/repo.git
```

The password is stored in .git\config

Any flags possible for the clone command so that GIT does not store the password in .git\config?

Comment: Is it an option to use `git clone https://user@server.com/repo.git`?

Comment: Nope :). I want to specify the password in the command itself.

Comment: Anything you do to remove the password after the fact is a case of (as the old saying goes) closing the barn door after the horse escapes. That said, it's easy enough to clone, then enter the clone directory and use `git remote set-url origin` to change the stored URL to remove the password. After, of course, some hacker has already extracted the password from where it was sitting in clear-text in `ps` output for the billions of nanoseconds the clone took to run. Never put passwords in cleartext.

Comment: @torek I didn't say I want to "remove the password after the fact". I said I don't want it to even STORE the password. As for hackers, if a hacker manages to get access to a computer in such a way that it can read my local console output, there's worse things to worry about :).

Comment: Unfortunately, Git's going to store it, because it saves the URL you gave it. Also, as I noted, if you type it in as clear-text, it goes into command line buffer, shell history files, and so on. It's true that there are many attack vectors (too much "surface area", as the security analysis types say) in the system, but this just gives attackers even more.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use clone.

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
git init
git pull https://user:password@server.com/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as described in comments. But if you insist on having a program which accepts password in  URL but stores it without one, you could make a wrapper which splits URL with password to URL and password, then runs `git close` with URL, and provides password to it as described in [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).